# How to set button clickability through Databinding

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding

I can set a progress bar's visibility through data binding easily by setting a binding adapter with a method such as following:

In the ViewModel:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:visibility")
fun setVisibility(view: View, visible: Boolean) {
    view.visibility = if (visible) View.INVISIBLE else View.VISIBLE
}
@Bindable
    var barProgress = ObservableField<Boolean>()

    fun makeVisible(){
        this.barProgress.set(true)
    }
    fun makeInvisible(){
        this.barProgress.set(false)
    }
```

In the layout xml:

```
android:visibility="@{!myViewModel.barProgress}"
```

can I in the same way assign `android:clickable` through this way or another? If I were to change the code the problem lies in there not being a View attribute suitable to this method. Trying to setEnabled() or setClickable() on the main method is not an option because I'm using coroutines and I think it conflicts with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I made it work as following:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:clickable")
fun setClickable(view: View, clickable: Boolean) {
    view.isClickable = !clickable
}

@Bindable
var clickable = ObservableField<Boolean>()

fun makeClickable(){
    this.clickable.set(true)
    }

fun makeUnclickable(){
    this.clickable.set(false)
    }
```

And in XML:

```
android:clickable="@{myViewModel.clickable}"
```

Bonus, setting the `enabled` attribute:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:enabled")
fun setEnabled(view: View, enabled: Boolean) {
    view.isEnabled = !enabled
}

@Bindable
var enabled = ObservableField<Boolean>()

fun makeEnabled(){
    this.enabled.set(true)
}

fun makeDisabled(){
    this.enabled.set(false)
}
```

and in xml:

```
android:enabled="@{myViewModel.enabled}"
```

I think you can guess how to do it for the `andorid:focusable` attribute.